# Values available in Microsoft.VSTS.Actions

Tags: tfs

I'm setting up a new workflow for a work item in TFS 2012. I've used the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.2 process template as the base. I'm adding some transitions and want to add an action similar to work completed/finished to one of them. I might also like to change some of the other actions, but I haven't been able to find a list of the options available anywhere. I know that it's possible to use my own actions, but I would like to know what Microsoft provide.

Do you know where there is a list?

Answer (score 1):

Up to TFS 2010 `Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin` was the only supported action out of the box.
From TFS 2012 `Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork` and `Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StopWork` added to support capturing work item transitions from in progress to stopped and vice versa.

- [Configuration Changes Made to Add New Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh913785%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Update Your Agile Team Project to Support Additional Functionality After You Upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS11 Beta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/03/06/get-your-agile-project-fixed-after-an-upgrade-from-tfs2010-to-tfs11-beta.aspx)

Comment: Is there an action for set Approved to Commited when a pull request is created?