# automated transition between states for work item types (WIT)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

I am using an on-premises Azure DevOps Server 2019

and I would like to enable automated transitions between states of a WIT (i.e. feature, bug), for example:

- move from *ToDo* to *Active*, when a branch is created/linked to the work item
- move from *Active* to *Under Review*, when a pull request is created for the linked branch

the transition element from my Feature.xml:

```
        <TRANSITION from="ToDo" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Implementation started" />
      </REASONS>
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate">
          <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy">
          <COPY from="currentuser" />
          <VALIDUSER />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
      <ACTIONS>
        <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.checkin" />
      </ACTIONS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

According to [Documentation for Automated State Transition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/automate-field-assignments-state-transition-reason?view=azure-devops#transition-action-details) it is possible to to handle the transition via the  element. I couldn't find any further info about the supported values.

Does anybody know, how to accomplish the automated transition?
the question relates to this [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428428/values-available-in-microsoft-vsts-actions)

Comment: In Azure DevOps, we do have two process models,On-premises XML process model and Inheritance process model.
For Azure DevOps Server 2019, you have a choice of process models. When you create a project collection, you'll need to choose between On-premises XML process model and Inheritance process model. What kind of process model are you using?

Comment: On-premises XML process model